# The Selection is Not a Type that Can Be Renamed Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

Trying to rename a class by selecting the class name (`ViewController`) after `@interface`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

Right clicking, selecting Refactor -> Rename results in the following error alert window:

[image]

This worked just fine in Xcode 6, is this some sort of regression? I tried [this solution for Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19816839/347339) to no avail. Anyone know of any work arounds?

Comment: Did you try Edit --> Refactoring > Rename?

Comment: Just tried, same result.

Comment: I wonder why your interface is not `@interface ViewController : UIViewController` or  `@interface ViewController ()`?

Comment: It is, just foolishly omitted it. Edited question to include entire line. This doesn't appear to be a compilation/syntax issue rather an IDE issue, but good eye.

Comment: It's an empty file you just created or it contains C++ code?

Comment: No, its a normal Objective C class with Objective C code fully functioning and working, I only posted the line I highlighted the class from. Nothing funny is being done, the code compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: It's a bug. Please file a report at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Yep filed a bug report. No workarounds though?

Comment: The same issue. Can not rename anything.

Comment: A great workaround is AppCode.  The navigation, code examination, refactoring, and other features make XCode laughable by comparison.

Comment: This is still not fixed in Xcode 7.1—unbelievable!

Comment: I've got this problem. But it's not an issue with all projects for me.

Comment: This fixed things for me, for unknown reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10513671/2799670

Comment: In 7.1 create a new iOS app from the MasterDetail template, then in MasterVC.m try to refactor the `objects` property...unbelievable...

Comment: This is still not fixed in Xcode 7.2 :(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: Still not fixed in Xcode 7.3!

Answer (score 27):

Yes, refactoring is badly broken in Xcode 7.

I have found similar problems when trying to rename properties, methods and classes. Yesterday I downloaded 7.1.1 with a hope that there might be some improvements but none so far.

I did some testing in a sample single view project in Objective-C on Xcode 7.1.1 and found the following:

1. If you try to rename a property that has IBOutlet keyword, it will fail;
2. If you try to rename another property which is not IBOutlet, but above it's declaration you have any property that is IBOutlet, rename will fail;
3. If you try to rename a method which is declared below IBOutlet property and do it right clicking the method in .h file, rename will fail;
4. **If you try to rename a class that #imports a class that has some IBOutlet declarations in the header file, rename will fail** (highlighted since this is the case, that original question is about).

Luckily I also found some workarounds:

1. If you move the declaration of your property above IBOutlet declarations, rename will succeed;
2. If you need to rename IBOutlet - you can move it above all other IBOutlets and remove the IBOutlet keyword of it before renaming it. Rename will succeed (and will also rename it within Storyboard), then you can add the IBOutlet keyword back;
3. If you move declaration of your method above any IBOutlet properties rename will succeed from .h file, but alternatively it also seems to work if you try to rename it when selecting in a .m file (the latter case works even if method is declared in .h file below IBoutlet properties);
4. When renaming class that imports another class with IBOutlets, you can do the following - move the IBOutlets of the other class from .h file to .m file. Then rename works. Alternatively - remove all IBOutlet keywords before the rename, and then add them back after it.

**Note:** When I say that rename succeeds, I mean - it won't show you "The selection is not a type that can be renamed". However it still does not work smoothly most of the time:

1. It does not show the changes to be made in files, like it used to do;
2. It may complain about the fact that files have been modified by another application while Xcode has unsaved changes. As I have found, usually you need to choose "Keep Xcode Version";
3. **It may fail to rename the property in all of the files it has been used. This is the most important, which in some cases make all the workarounds useless.** Specifically I've seen it when renaming IBOutlet properties with method I've described above.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For IBOutlets, global find/replace is a reasonable alternative, although you have to be careful since it's only text based, and can match more than you intended.

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
In my case i needed to rename `implementation class name` so i just commented `// IBOutlet` in header then made `refactor -> rename` and uncommented `IBOutlet`

Answer (score 5):

One way to workaround this issue until it is corrected in Xcode is add a forward declaration to the header file (in a separate line above the @interface line). Like this:

```
@class ClassName
```

After it is added, do the rename on this, instead of on the @interface line. You can remove the forward declaration after renaming

Comment: I am also using 7.2.  I guess until it is properly fixed by Apple, people just have to try the different options, and hopefully one of them works for you.  Probably the next time I try using the forward declaration, it won't work.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Can you please explain it in more detail, for example making more clear if I have to add 1 line or modify the existing one, and the exact changes?  Do this workaround works if I want to rename a method or a variable?

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify.  This only works for renaming a class but doesn't work for everybody.

Comment: I have idea why this works, but it works on Xcode 8.2.1.